# sequelize js: database not being created properly

Tags: sequelize.js

So I just created a database using sequelize.js for node and have this code:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'sheta', 'mysqlroot', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
   timestamps: false
});

var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    userID: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    userName: Sequelize.TEXT,
    password: Sequelize.TEXT
}, {
    instanceMethods: {
        getUserId: function() {
            return this.userID;
        }
    }
});

var Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    userID: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    postText: Sequelize.TEXT,
    date: Sequelize.DATE,
    postID: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, {
    instanceMethods: {
        getPost: function() {
            return this.postText;
        }  
    }
});

var Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
    postID: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    commentText: Sequelize.TEXT,
    date: Sequelize.DATE,
    commentID: Sequelize.INTEGER 
} , {
    instanceMethods: {
        getComment: function() {
            return this.commentText;
        }
    }
});

var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    tagID: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    tagText: Sequelize.TEXT,
    postID: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

//Associations
Post.belongsTo(User);
Post.hasOne(User);
User.hasMany(Post);
Post.hasMany(Comment);
Comment.belongsTo(User);
Comment.hasOne(User);
User.hasMany(Comment);
Post.hasMany(Tag);
Tag.hasMany(Post);

sequelize.sync();
```

But when I try to add a tuple using:

```
User.create({ userID: 1, userName: 'sam', password: 'th'}).success(function(task) {
    console.log("inserted");
    // you can now access the newly created task via the variable task
});
```

the "inserted" never prints.
Am I doing something wrong? I mainly looked at the code on sequelize js. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: you must ensure that the table is created. I recommend you to create a script to initialize your database/table. Don't mix it in your application code.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of suggestions as for what your problem might be.

You said that you created your database using sequelize - you have to have a database created already, sequelize only creates the tables - just checking ;-)

Could you please attach an `.error` or `.done` function to the `sequelize.sync` and `User.create` calls and post the errors that appear

Comment: How do you import an existing database into sequelize.js?

Comment: You don't 'import' a database as such. You have to options: Either you can create the database yourself and create sequelize models that match, without ever calling sync - or you can create all the models in sequelize and call `.sync()` which will create the database tables for you. From your code it seems you are taking the later approach - Did you try attaching the error callbacks?